# Using the result of a Promise in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-promise

I'm trying to access a Promise (an array of file paths) created in **recursive.js** (goes through my directories and sorts my stylesheets) in my **webpack.config.js** so I can compile all my stylesheets in a specific order.

It seems that **webpack.config.js** is not able to access the result from **recursive.js** and it is not generating my bundle of .css/.scss files!

I actually can't think of a way to solve this...I thought that having the *module.exports = { ... }* inside *.then( result => { ... } )* would be enough...but it I believe that module.exports tries to use result before it's even ready and it only generates *main.js*

**recursive.js**

```
const readdirp = require('readdirp');

let files = readdirp.promise('src/lib/bs4',
    {
        entryType: 'files', fileFilter: ['*.css', '*.scss'], directoryFilter: ['!modulos', '!node_modules', '!assets']
    })
    .then(function (files) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(promises = files.map(files => files.path))
        })
    }).then(function (result) {
        let cssArr = []
        let scssArr = []
        result.forEach(e => {
            let temp = e.split('.')
            if (temp[temp.length - 1] === 'css') {
                cssArr.push(e)
                //cssArr.push(e.replace(/\\/g, '/'))
            } else {
                scssArr.push(e)
                //scssArr.push(e.replace(/\\/g, '/'))
            }
        })
        console.log(cssArr.concat(scssArr))
        return cssArr.concat(scssArr)
    })

exports.files = files
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ext = require('./recursive')


ext.files.then((result) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(promises = result.map(e => e = path.resolve(__dirname, `src/lib/bs4/${e}`)))
    // .map(e => e.replace(/\\/g, '/')))
  })
})
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result) // prints out the expected array of file paths!

    module.exports = {
      entry: {
        bundle: result,
        main: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/principal')
        ]
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ]
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: "[name].css"
        }),
      ]
    };

  })
```

I believe I shouldn't be using *module.exports* in my **webpack.config.js** file inside **.then((result) => { } )**.

Are there another ways around this?

Thanks, guys!

**UPDATE**

I read bit more to try and understand what FZs and Steve Holgado (Thanks a lot!) were trying to explain, and I modified my code to behave like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const readdirp = require('readdirp');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

// extracts argument (path) from script command
const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

// development or production?
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const configPromise = readdirp.promise('src/lib/bs4',
  {
    // if a file (stylesheets/images) is not being imported/required its extension needs to be added to the fileFilter: []
    // e.g.: removing '*.png' won't bundle images from 'src\lib\bs4\imgs'
    entryType: 'files', fileFilter: ['*.css', '*.scss', '*.png'], directoryFilter: ['!modulos', '!node_modules', '!assets']
  })
  .then(function (files) {
    return files = files.map(file => file.path);
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let cssArr = [];
      let scssArr = [];
      result.forEach(element => {
        let temp = element.split('.');

        (temp[temp.length - 1] === 'css') ? cssArr.push(element) : scssArr.push(element)

      })

      // .scss files first then .css
      result = scssArr.concat(cssArr);
      result = result.map(element => path.resolve(__dirname, `src/lib/bs4/${element}`));

      // Path to the first file in the queue (src/..)
      if (!args['path']) {
        console.log(' ******* Path to main stylesheet NOT added ******* ');
      } else {
        console.log(' ******* Path to main stylesheet ADDED ******* ');
        result.unshift(path.resolve(__dirname, args['path']));
      }

      // console.log(args['path'])
      // console.log(result)

      resolve({
        mode: devMode ? 'development' : 'production',
        entry: {
          // main: './src/principal.js',
          // bundle.css
          bundle: result,
        },
        output: {
          // filename: 'principal.js',
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundle-css'),
        },
        optimization: {
          minimizer: devMode ? [] : [
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
              assetNameRegExp: /\.css$/,
            })
          ]
        },  
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
              use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // 3. Extract css into files
                'css-loader', // 2. Turns css into commonjs
                'sass-loader' // 1. Turns sass into css
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'file-loader',
                  options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'images/',
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'file-loader',
                  options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'fonts/',
                    exclude: /images/, // avoid having copies of .svg fonts into 'images/'
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
        },
        plugins: [
          new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: devMode ? '[name].[hash].css' : '[name].[hash].min.css'
          }),
          new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['bundle-css'] // clean output.path directory
          })
        ]
      })
    })
  })

module.exports = configPromise
```

Here are the commands I'm using to run it in case someone needs help with that too:

```
  "scripts": {
    "bundle-css-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config ./bundle-css.config.js --progress --colors",
    "bundle-css-prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./bundle-css.config.js --progress --colors"
  },
```

To run one of the scripts: npm run bundle-css-dev -- --path="path_to_first_file_in_queue"

Comment: You can set `module.exports` to your promise, and wait for it in *main.js*...

Comment: Would mind providing a sample code? Thanks, @FZs

Comment: That was just a quick guess... I don't really understand your code (because I'm unfamiliar with some modules you're using...), but I've meant: `module.exports=somePromise` instead of `somePromise.then((result) => {module.exports=result } )`; and then in the other file: `require('your_file').then(result=>{/*use result here*/})` instead of `const result=require('your_file'); /*use result here*/`... I hope you understand what I'm talking about  ;)

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export a function from **webpack.config.js** and return a promise.

Webpack will wait for the promise to resolve:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ext = require('./recursive')

module.exports = () => {
  return ext.files
    .then((result) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(promises = result.map(e => e = path.resolve(__dirname, `src/lib/bs4/${e}`)))
        // .map(e => e.replace(/\\/g, '/')))
      })
    })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result) // prints out the expected array of file paths!

      return {
        entry: {
          bundle: result,
          main: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/principal')
          ]
        },
        output: {
          filename: '[name].js',
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
              use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
              ]
            },
          ],
        },
        plugins: [
          new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css"
          }),
        ]
      }
    })
}
```